# Create an aws integration in Http API using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-http-api

I'm using AWS CDK to build a cloudformation stack with HttpApi in it.
HttpApi will have an integration with SQS.

I have the following snippet:

```js
import * as ApiGW2 from "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha";

const httpApi = new ApiGW2.HttpApi(this, "http-api", {
  apiName: "dev-api"
});

const int = new ApiGW2.HttpIntegration(this, "int1", {
  httpApi,
  integrationType: ApiGW2.HttpIntegrationType.AWS_PROXY,
  integrationSubtype: ApiGW2.HttpIntegrationSubtype.SQS_SEND_MESSAGE,
  payloadFormatVersion: ApiGW2.PayloadFormatVersion.VERSION_1_0,
})
```

But I get an error when running this code:

> UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Role ARN must be specified for AWS
> integration configuration with Subtype: SQS-SendMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Gateway service [needs permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-aws-services.html) to send messages to your queue.  Create a role assumable by the API Gateway service.  Grant the role send permissions on your queue.  Pass the role to the integration in the [credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigatewayv2-alpha.HttpIntegration.html#credentialsspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan) prop:

```js
const sqsRole = new iam.Role(this, "Role", {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("apigateway.amazonaws.com"),
});

myQueue.grantSendMessages(sqsRole);

const credentials = ApiGW2.IntegrationCredentials.fromRole(sqsRole);

const int = new ApiGW2.HttpIntegration(this, "int1", {
  httpApi,
  integrationType: ApiGW2.HttpIntegrationType.AWS_PROXY,
  integrationSubtype: ApiGW2.HttpIntegrationSubtype.SQS_SEND_MESSAGE,
  payloadFormatVersion: ApiGW2.PayloadFormatVersion.VERSION_1_0,
  credentials, // <-- connects the role to the integration
})
```

Comment: Thanks @fedonev! It works, the integration gets created but I can't use it in addRoute of HttpApi. 

    httpApi.addRoutes({
      path: "/toSqs",
      integration: int
    })

I’ve got compile error: Type  HttpIntegration  is missing the following properties from type  HttpRouteIntegratio

Comment: Glad to help, @AlexanderKondaurov.  See the open GitHub issue [apigatewayv2-integrations: Add support for SQS-SendMessage integration](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/24785).  The comments include a DIY implementation of a `HttpRouteIntegration` class for SQS-SendMessage.